# Object reference not set to an instance of an object (unable to access database on server)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I developed my application on dotnet trial version and implemented on server. My organization basically uses Sharepoint. Application runs fine on local host but I am unable to run it on server. I cannot debug it on visual studio due to compliance issue now.
 Please help.

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.
>
> Source Error:
>
> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]    WebTrackingTool.DBFiles.DBRepository.GetLogin(String
>   UserName, String UserPassword) in
>   C:\Project\WebTrackingTool\WebTrackingTool\DBFiles\DBRepository.cs:217
>   WebTrackingTool.Login.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Project\WebTrackingTool\WebTrackingTool\Login.aspx.cs:22
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319;
>   ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272

Comment: putting your code instead for this big error message will give you better response

Comment: `NullReferenceException` is a common situation for beginner programmers. The link provided should help you understand the problem. Then use the debugger to find what/where/when you have a variable that is `null`. And next time, please show your code as well. It is not possible to help you without see your work.

Comment: What is _dotnet trial version_?  What specific version are you using?

Comment: hello! I used VS 2015. I deployed my project to sharepoint. But it is not working there. I get error that says :[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
   WebTrackingTool.DBFiles.DBRepository.GetLogin(String UserName, String UserPassword) in C:\Project\WebTrackingTool\WebTrackingTool\DBFiles\DBRepository.cs:217 ........................................ Does it mean that it is still finding the local path to access the database? Please help